# Why doesn't my equalSign function work when run?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to build a basic calculator website using javascript and HTML. All my other functions work properly like they should but my equalSign function does not do anything. Not sure why it does not work and why nothing is happening.Why doesn't my function work? Is it the onclick property or the actual code in the function itself?

```js
let display = 0;

function square() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display * display;
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function cube() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display * display * display;
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function root() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = Math.sqrt(display);
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function clearDisplay() {
  display = 0;
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function seven() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 7
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function eight() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 8
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function nine() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 9
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function four() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 4
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function five() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 5
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function six() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 6
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function one() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 1
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function two() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 2
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function three() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 3
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function zero() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + 0
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function decimal() {
  display = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = display + '.'
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
}

function add() {
  num1 = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = '+'
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
  let oper = '+';
  return oper;
}

function subtract() {
  num1 = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = '-'
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
  let oper = '-';
  return oper;
}

function multiply() {
  num1 = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = '*'
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
  let oper = '*';
  return oper;
}

function divide() {
  num1 = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  display = '/'
  document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = display;
  let oper = '/';
  return oper;
}

function equalSign(oper, num1) {
  num2 = document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML
  if (oper == '+') {
    let sum = num1 + num2;
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = sum;
  } else if (oper == '-') {
    let sum = num1 - num2;
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = sum;
  } else if (oper == '*') {
    let sum = num1 * num2;
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = sum;
  } else if (oper == '/') {
    let sum = num1 / num2;
    document.querySelector('#display').innerHTML = sum;
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#dislay').innerHTML = "ERROR";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class='bigbox' id="display">0</h1>
<div>
  <button class="button" style="font-size: 24px" onclick="square(); return         false">x²</button>
  <button class="button" style="font-size: 23px" onclick="cube(); return false">x³</button>
  <button class="button" style="font-size: 24px" onclick="root(); return false">√x</button>
  <button class="ce" onclick="clearDisplay(); return false">CE</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="button" onclick="seven(); return false">7</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="eight(); return false">8</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="nine(); return false">9</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="divide(); return false">/</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="button" onclick="four(); return false">4</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="five(); return false">5</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="six(); return false">6</button>
  <button class="button" style="font-size: 30px" onclick="multiply(); return false">*</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="button" onclick="one(); return false">1</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="two(); return false">2</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="three(); return false">3</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="subtract(); return false">-</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="button" onclick="zero(); return false">0</button>
  <button class="button" style="font-size: 50px" onclick="decimal(); return false">.</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="equalSign(oper); return false">=</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="add(); return false">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: oper is not defined`.

Comment: `onclick="equalSign(oper);` ... you don't have a global variable `oper`, and the function expects two arguments.

Comment: also: `#display` is misspelled `#dislay` in the final (ERROR) case of `equalSign()`

Comment: So... maybe learn to look in the brower's console. It helps to find out where things go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into two problems here. First off, `equalSign` is declared with 2 parameters `oper` and `num1`, but you only pass it one `oper`. Second, `oper`is never declared before you call you try to pass it to `equalSign` in the buttons `onClick` function.

Id recommend changing the button to:

```html
 <button class="button" onclick="equalSign(); return false">=</button>
```

As for the JavaScript, I cant give a specific recommendation on how to rework it as I don't know how you were intending to get num1, but both parameters for `equalSign` should probabaly be top level variables like `display` is.